# How to import the environment variables from the parent branch in a forked repo (GitLab)?

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm setting up a Gitlab runner to SSH into a remote server so I can run tests on physical hardware, however the jobs fail when launched from my forked branch. I save the SSH keys as environment variables in the parent and they are not picked up by the jobs running on the forked runners. How can I import the environment variables from the parent?

The jobs are successful when I manually add the SSH key as an environment variable to my forked repo, however this is not scalable. I have tried adding the project and all people involved to a common group and set the same variables in there, as well as initiate Group Runners. It seems that if you kickoff a runner from your personal account then you cannot access the necessary variables.

In the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I added some print out statements to help debug. I set the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` and `RUNNER_ID` to their required values in the parent repo and left unassigned in my forked branch. I got blank outputs when run from my personal account.

gitlab-ci.yml

```
hardware-1:
  image: ubuntu
  before_script:
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
    - echo "$RUNNER_ID"
  tags:
    - hardware
  script:
    - ssh pi@raspberry "./test-hardware.sh"
```

Runner console output on forked repo.

```
$ ...
$ Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
$ 0 added, 0 removed; done.
$ Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"

$ echo "$RUNNER_ID"
```

On the parent branch, the console outputs the actual SSH_PRIVATE_KEY and RUNNER_ID. How to I force the runner to always run from the parent repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It might be because of this:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#protected-environment-variables)

Variables can be protected. Whenever a variable is protected, it would only be securely passed to pipelines running on the protected branches or protected tags. The other pipelines would not get any protected variables.

Protected variables can be added by going to your project’s Settings > CI/CD, then finding the section called Variables, and check “Protected”.

Once you set them, they will be available for all subsequent pipelines.

To protect a branch or a tag:

Settings -> Repository -> Protected branches/tags